# Identify duplicate values when using JOIN in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables that hold values for customers. The first table holds the names of the customer and the second holds information relating to the customer such as transactions.

The first table looks like

```
CustomerID    Name
1             Joe
2             Jane
```

The second table looks like

```
TransactID    CustomerID    Reference
1             1             REF123
2             2             REF123
3             1             REF321
```

I need to able to identify all duplicates in the reference column as well as the customer it belongs to e.g. Joe, Jane

The code i have at the moment looks like

```
SELECT o.name, COUNT(p.reference) as RefCount
FROM (t_cust as o
INNER JOIN t_custprop as p
         ON o.customerid = p.customerid)
GROUP BY o.name, p.reference
HAVING (COUNT(p.reference)>1) 
ORDER BY o.name ASC
```

As i don't know the possible values that may be duplicates, the code above doesn't return the name of the customer and the reference that may be a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure, does Acccess have a `DINSTINCT` statement?

Comment: Try changing COUNT(p.reference) to COUNT(*) to count number of rows. Do it in both the select list and the having clause.

Comment: What result set are you expecting from your example? You want `REF123, Joe` and `REF123, Jane` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by the item you're counting will always result in the count being 1, which is eliminated by your having clause. This should to the trick:

```
SELECT o.name, p.reference
FROM t_cust o
    INNER JOIN t_custprop p ON o.customerid = p.customerid
WHERE p.reference IN (
    SELECT p2.reference
    FROM t_custprop p2
    GROUP BY p2.reference
    HAVING COUNT(p2.customerid) > 1
    )
ORDER BY o.name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and get the error message `Too few parameters. Expected 2`

Comment: Nothing in this statement calls functions that require parameters, save for count(). I tried it on my side using the test data you supplied and got the expected results of Jane/Joe for REF123. If there's a problem further down the line, isolate it and ask a new question.